# What is difference the service uuids and the service solicitation uuids from bluetooth scan result?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ads, bluetoothlescanner

I'm studying for bluetooth advertising data.
If I trigger bluetooth scan on my device, remote device's advertising data will be delivered as a result.
There are service uuids and service solicitation uuids on advertising data.
But, I don't know what is difference two uuids.

Comment: Explained here: https://blog.bluetooth.com/advertising-works-part-2

Comment: Thank you @RolandWeber!!